# Checking STOP time of EC2 instance with boto3

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

Python 2.7
Boto3

I'm trying to get a timestamp of when the instance was stopped OR the time the last state transition took place OR a duration of how long the instance has been in the current state.

My goal is to test if an instance has been stopped for x hours.

For example,

```
instance = ec2.Instance('myinstanceID')
if int(instance.state['Code']) == 80:
    stop_time = instance.state_change_time() #Dummy method.
```

Or something similar to that.

I see that boto3 has a `launch_time` method. And lots of ways to analyze state changes using `state_transition_reason` and `state_reason` but I'm not seeing anything regarding the state transition timestamp.

I've got to be missing something.

Here is the Boto3 docs for Instance "state" methods...

```
state
(dict) --

The current state of the instance.

Code (integer) --

The low byte represents the state. The high byte is an opaque internal value and should be ignored.

0 : pending
16 : running
32 : shutting-down
48 : terminated
64 : stopping
80 : stopped
Name (string) --

The current state of the instance.


state_reason
(dict) --

The reason for the most recent state transition.

Code (string) --

The reason code for the state change.

Message (string) --

The message for the state change.

Server.SpotInstanceTermination : A Spot instance was terminated due to an increase in the market price.
Server.InternalError : An internal error occurred during instance launch, resulting in termination.
Server.InsufficientInstanceCapacity : There was insufficient instance capacity to satisfy the launch request.
Client.InternalError : A client error caused the instance to terminate on launch.
Client.InstanceInitiatedShutdown : The instance was shut down using the shutdown -h command from the instance.
Client.UserInitiatedShutdown : The instance was shut down using the Amazon EC2 API.
Client.VolumeLimitExceeded : The limit on the number of EBS volumes or total storage was exceeded. Decrease usage or request an increase in your limits.
Client.InvalidSnapshot.NotFound : The specified snapshot was not found.


state_transition_reason
(string) --

The reason for the most recent state transition. This might be an empty string.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The EC2 instance has an attribute `StateTransitionReason` which also has the time the transition happened. Use Boto3 to get the time the instance was stopped.

```
print status['StateTransitionReason']
...
User initiated (2016-06-23 23:39:15 GMT)
```

The code below prints stopped time and current time. Use Python to parse the time and find the difference. Not very difficult if you know Python.

```
import boto3
import re

client = boto3.client('ec2')
rsp = client.describe_instances(InstanceIds=['i-03ad1f27'])
if rsp:
  status = rsp['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]
  if status['State']['Name'] == 'stopped':
    stopped_reason = status['StateTransitionReason']
    current_time = rsp['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPHeaders']['date']
    stopped_time = re.findall('.*\((.*)\)', stopped_reason)[0]
    print 'Stopped time:', stopped_time
    print 'Current time:', current_time
```

Output

```
Stopped time: 2016-06-23 23:39:15 GMT
Current time: Tue, 20 Dec 2016 20:33:22 GMT
```

Comment: As of Jan 22, 2020, the time is no longer included in the 'StateTransitionReason' field. I don't know when they removed it...

Comment: @Zchpyvr That's weird, I still get them in the response - `StateTransitionReason: 'User initiated (2020-01-30 03:10:43 GMT)'`

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna What region are you using? It may be region-specific?

Comment: @Zchpyvr I'm using `ap-southeast-1` region. Let me try in a different region as well and check.

Comment: My team runs boto3 Lambdas in multiple regions around the world that utilize the data in StateTransitionReason. datetime has not been removed from that value.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using **AWS Config** to [view the configuration history](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/get-config-history-cli.html) of the instances.

> **AWS Config** is a fully managed service that provides you with an AWS resource inventory, **configuration history**, and configuration change notifications to enable security and governance

The [`get-resource-config-history`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configservice/get-resource-config-history.html) command can return information about an instance, so it probably has Stop & Start times. It will take a bit of parsing to extract the details.