# AWS stopped instances list since last 7 days ,how can get?

Tags: yaml

List of AWS stopped instances since last 7 days , how do we get please provide solution.

Comment: Does [checking-stop-time-of-ec2-instance-with-boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41231630/checking-stop-time-of-ec2-instance-with-boto3) solve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the event occurred in the last 90 days, then you can get more information about the event using AWS CloudTrail logs. To view the event on CloudTrail, follow these steps:

- Open the CloudTrail console.
- In the navigation pane, choose Event history.
- In the Lookup attributes dropdown menu, select Event name.
- For Enter an event name, enter StopInstances if your instance was stopped. Enter RebootInstances if your instance was rebooted.
- Enter TerminateInstances if your instance was terminated.
- To see more information about an event, choose the event name. On the StopInstances, RebootInstances, or TerminateInstances event details page, you can see the user name of the AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) user that initiated the event.

**Ref:**[How can I find who stopped, rebooted, or terminated my EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-windows-identify-stop-reboot/)

Comment: Accepted with your answer but is there any other way to find...?

Comment: @Saimohanranga did you check https://stackoverflow.com/a/41250935/13779320 ?